# how to solve authentication error when sending email with python

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to send an email with python using a gmail account however I am an authentication error.I have verified the email address and the password but there is no problem.I have even enable less secure app in gmail

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import os
import smtplib

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465, context = context) as 
smtp:
    smtp.login('monitorweight100@gmail.com','monitor weight')
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'confirm weight'
    msg['From'] = 'monitorweight100@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = 'helloworld@gmail.com'
    msg.set_content('Detected recent activity')
    msg.add_alternative("""\
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?           
family=Niramit" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <body style="margin:0;">
                    <h1>Did you recently weigh yourself?</h1>
                    <img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiOrNW1xPfkAhV57OAKHcZoDKAQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconfinder.com%2Ficons%2F3776312%2Fcontrol_diet_healthcare_medical_examination_monitor_scale_weight_icon&psig=AOvVaw2j4tjnCN0wRNR_voOfWKMZ&ust=1569898092735783" alt= "monitorweight" width="900" height="300">
                    <p>Dear User</p>
                    <p>We found some weight that was from your wii    
balance board,was it you?</p>
                    <p>Please confirm that it was you by clicking   
on the link below</p>

                    <button><a href="https://www.google.com">Click    
to confirm</button>

            </body>
            </html>
            """,subtype='html')

smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com',465)    
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.sendmail('monitorweight100@gmail.com','helloworld@gmail.com',msg)
smtp.quit()



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/smart-scale/mailtest.py", line 36, in <module>
    smtp.sendmail('monitorweight100@gmail.com','helloworld@gmail.com',msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 862, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required.     Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError     h125sm29106842wmf.31 - gsmtp', 'monitorweight100@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging in with **monitorweight@gmail.com** and trying to set **From** to a different one, **monitorweight100@gmail.com**.
Keep them the same & the problem should be solved.
And btw **msg** is sufficient for the *smtp.sendmali()*.
try this..

```
msg['From'] = 'monitorweight@gmail.com'
# other codes...

smtp.semdmail(msg)
```